# Find 'missing' rows across two result sets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've been struggling with this for days so apologies if I've over-confused things...

I have a series of tables that define:

1. Groups of skills
2. Skills
3. Skills within the above groups (many-to-many)
4. Job roles
5. The skills with those job roles (many-to-many)

The structure of the database looks like this:
[image: Schema]

I need to create a result set that displays the following data:

> For all of the job roles, show all of the skills within those job
>   roles.  However, also include skills within the respective groups that
>   were **not included** in each role (indicated with NULL or by any
>   other method).

Please see this working code to create the tables and data.  [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/11464)
Apologies for the length, I did lots of inserts to create a realistic example.

Notice that the `PowerPoint` skill is not added to the `HR Manager` role, but other skills from that same group are added.  Also notice that the `Recruitment Policy` skill is not added to the `Software Manager` role, but I do not need to see this gap because no other skills in that group exist in the role.

The results I would aim for would resemble this (excludes Super Star role for brevity):

```
RoleTitle               GroupTitle                 SkillTitle               SkillIsInRole
----------------------- -------------------------- --------------------------------------
Software Manager        Microsoft Office           Excel                    1
Software Manager        Microsoft Office           Word                     1
Software Manager        Microsoft Office           PowerPoint               1
Software Manager        Microsoft SQL Server       Query Design             1
Software Manager        Microsoft SQL Server       Stored Procedures        1
Software Manager        Microsoft SQL Server       Failover Clustering      1
HR Manager              Microsoft Office           Excel                    1
HR Manager              Microsoft Office           Word                     1
HR Manager              Microsoft Office           PowerPoint               NULL <-- not added to role but exists in same group as other used skills
HR Manager              HR                         Recruitment Policy       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting all skills for a group related to a role is somewhat simple and is handled in the relatively self explanatory `roles` cte below. From this the only way I can think of obtaining whether the skill was related 'directly' to the role is by `OUTER APPLY`ING the result set to the result set of actual skills for role.

```
;WITH skills AS
(
  SELECT g.GroupId, g.GroupTitle, s.SkillId, s.SkillTitle
  FROM @tbl_GroupsSkills gs
  INNER JOIN @tbl_Groups g ON g.GroupId = gs.GroupId
  INNER JOIN @tbl_Skills s ON s.SkillId = gs.SkillId
)
, roles AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT jr.Id RoleId, jr.RoleTitle, gs.GroupId
  FROM @tbl_jobroles jr
  INNER JOIN @tbl_rolesskills rs ON rs.RoleId = jr.ID
  INNER JOIN @tbl_GroupsSkills gs ON gs.LinkId = rs.LinkId
)
SELECT 
    roles.RoleTitle, 
    skills.GroupTitle, 
    skills.SkillTitle,
    t.SkillIsInRole
FROM skills
JOIN roles ON roles.GroupId = skills.GroupId
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT 1 SkillIsInRole
  FROM @tbl_rolesskills rs 
  INNER JOIN @tbl_jobroles r ON rs.RoleID = r.ID 
  INNER JOIN @tbl_groupsskills gs ON gs.LinkID = rs.LinkID 
  INNER JOIN @tbl_groups g ON g.groupID = gs.GroupID 
  INNER JOIN @tbl_skills s ON s.skillID = gs.SkillID
  WHERE s.SkillId = skills.SkillId
  AND g.GroupId = skills.GroupId
  AND r.Id = roles.RoleId
) t
ORDER BY roles.RoleTitle, skills.GroupTitle, skills.SkillTitle
```

Edit: the `OUTER APPLY` could be handled with a `LEFT JOIN`

```
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT s.SkillId, g.GroupId, r.Id RoleId, 1 SkillIsInRole
  FROM @tbl_rolesskills rs 
  INNER JOIN @tbl_jobroles r ON rs.RoleID = r.ID 
  INNER JOIN @tbl_groupsskills gs ON gs.LinkID = rs.LinkID 
  INNER JOIN @tbl_groups g ON g.groupID = gs.GroupID 
  INNER JOIN @tbl_skills s ON s.skillID = gs.SkillID
) t ON t.SkillId = skills.SkillId
   AND t.GroupId = skills.GroupId
   AND t.RoleId = roles.RoleId
```

[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/11557)

Comment: Thanks enormously.  I'll try it in the morning when I am back at work.

Comment: Stunning.  Thanks very much. I'll be looking at your 'tba' web site and when you're looking for a new job I'll be checking if our finances allow it :-)

Comment: Just a quick question please.  Your query executes a fraction faster than Bogdan's yet has much more code.  Do you have any info about why that might be?  I chose your answer as the correct one purely because of this.

Comment: Where did you check execution time of both queries? I don't claim that my is faster, I think that they have to have similar execution time.

Comment: Hi Bogdan.  I checked in SMSS Client Statistics on the test data.  Your answer was slower, but only by a fraction.  I think your answer is easier to read though and am using that in my work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to prepare a set of all possible combinations Roles from one side and Group-skills from the other. This is done by making Decart multiplication (usually done by CROSS JOIN). As a result you will have a list of each role combined with a list of all possible Group-skills combinations. After that you can LEFT JOIN this result with table tbl_RolesSkills. This will give what you need. You can do this by using CTE or sub query.

Have to looks like [this example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/11575)

Actually CROSS JOIN is not needed, I missed part with "specific roles have only a specific group sets". Only one sub-query, can be done also with CTE (Common table expression).

I also exclude "Super Star" role. If you want to add it just remove WHERE section.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please post an example in the SQL Fiddle script?

Comment: Sorry, I write answer from iPad, and on it is hard for me to write scripts :)

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you very much. Really appreciate you taking the time to understand my example.